# Is there any php function to get csv data as mysql select query

Tags: php, select, csv

I am working with several csv files.
In mysql SELECT col FROM table WHERE id = '11';
It is the method where I would obtain all records where id = 11.
I am searching for php function like this SELECT column/title FROM file.csv WHERE id ='11'.
Then it may returns all records with id= '11'.

Comment: What? Can you rewrite your question? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Are your csv files stored in a Mysql table?

Comment: No. My csv files in filesystem.

Comment: If I'm getting it correctly, you can not get rows from file.csv like an sql statement with "where". you need to either import the csv file into db system or fetch all rows from csv file and check row with id=11 using php

Comment: How do I cheek row where id 11 exist. Can you provide it?

Answer (score 0):

Using fgetcsv you can read in the file row wise. Simply store the rows in arrays which have the relevant search keys as index. Thus you will have an array with key 11 that has an array of rows as value.
Alternatively store the data in a memory database and query it with SQL.

Comment: Actually I have searched for the function csvread() in php.net but there is not appeared this. I know fgetcsv() function and I am not satisfied with it cause it has no query privilage.

Comment: Sorry, yes, fgetcsv is the correct function. As I said you either have to build up a simple array base index or put the data into a database. There is no build in search function for CSV files.

Comment: MySQL `load` might help on import